# Why is Google showing a wrong preview for this search?

Tags: discussion, google

I searched Google for `elb add hsts headers`, and the first result is a SO question titled ["How to implement HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) on AWS Elastic Load Balancer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025426/how-to-implement-http-strict-transport-security-hsts-on-aws-elastic-load-balan), but the Google result shows a "Not the answer you're looking for? Browse other questions tagged ..." title.

[image: Google screenshot]

Comment: Aren't the only people who could answer this Google employees?

Comment: The text in Google is *present on the page*, as an `H2` element; the real question title is a `H1` element. So in all likely-hood this is Google bug. Note that the `H2` element actually contains some of your search keywords though!

Answer (score 3):

That collection of keywords seems to be more prominent in the `<h2>` footer than the question title is my best guess but more likely it is a bug. Particularly the `elb` and `hsts`.

[image]